# How to save IAR IDE disassembly window contents to a file?

Tags: c, embedded, disassembly, iar

Using IAR IDE for building ARM executables from C source, I can see the disassembly, including labels, addresses, opcode and instructions in the relevant window.

I am trying to dump the contents of a range of addresses to a text file, but can't find a way to do that. The window text is not selectable so I cannot use copy/paste. There is no menu associated that enables this.

As an alternative, I can generate the list and assembly files, but these seem to be limited to my code, and do not contain the CRT code or any ROM sections, which I am interested in.

Any way to dump a selected address range?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to use `ielfdumparm` located in your Workbench directory under arm/bin. Here's the help for the tool.

```
Usage:          IElfDump input_file [output_file]

Available command line options:
--all           Dump all sections
--code          Dump only code sections
--no_header     Do not produce a list header
--no_rel_sections
                Do not output associated .rel sections
--no_strtab     Do not include strtab sections
--output file
-o file         Name of text file to create
--raw           Use raw text format
--section #|name[,...]
-s #|name[,...] Dump only section(s) with given numbers/names
--source        Include source in disassembled code in executables
--use_full_std_template_names
                Don't use short names for standard C++ templates
-a              All sections, except strtab sections
-f file         Read command line options from file
```

To get a similar output to the debug view, I would suggest `--code` to avoid dumping your data space, and `--source` to have it embed your original C woven in with the assembly.

You can specify sections, but it doesn't look like you can specify address range. You may be able to pair this with some of the other ELF tools to extract just a specific address range, and then run this tool on that. Alternatively, this dumps in address order so you could dump the entire ELF file and then just look at the address range you want after the fact.

Comment: The version I have installed does allow an address range to be specified: `--range A-B     Disassemble only addresses in the specified range (from A to B).`

Comment: Do you mind if I ask what version? I'm running behind in versions, but it sounds like there could be some nice improvements.

Comment: `IAR ELF Dumper V6.60.1.5097 for ARM`

Answer (score 1):

I use Snagit to capture text that is not selectable.
Snagit is a screen snapshot tool (a very good one). Besides making classic screen shots it supports to capture text and save it as ASCII text. It can also automatically scroll windows to capture long texts.

Maybe it is worth a try. There is a 30-day trial version available.

Comment: Nice, but when the code spans on more than 1 window length (as is the usual case), then this can become very tedious. Plus, it is not a free tool ;-)

Comment: +1, though, for it *does* give some limited solution to the problem.